# How do I call a function once the user scrolls to a certain page anchor?

Tags: jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I am using the plugin fullpage.js and I want to call a function in at a specific point in the page--namely, to not allow scrolling down until that function has animated a new element, and then again allow scrolling once that animation is done. If it's the first section, how do I use "onload"? I have no idea how to structure this.

This is what the creator of the plugin told me on github: "You could use setAllowScrolling(false) on the onLoad callback of the section you want to stick, then load your contents or your animations and then use setAllowScrolling(true) again." Here's my issue below, I asked for coding help on Github which I now realize isn't the right place for that...

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/801

What he said makes perfect sense to me logically, but I'm not sure where to start and am short on time so any help in how to structure it would mean the world to me.

I want to animate the "uk-flag" element in before the user can get to Section Two:

```
<div class="section" id="section-one">
  <div class="uk-flag"></div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-two">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here's a slightly dysfunctional [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4odo4exu/1/) I just whipped up...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: just added one... @LloydBanks

Comment: I looked at your fiddle.  The flag is loading just fine and covers up `#section-two`.  What behavior are you looking for that isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you expect, you should use the `setTimeout()` javascript function.
Using the `setTimeout()` callback you can then execute whatever you want after the delay.
For example you can disable mouse scroll using `setAllowScrolling(false)` and move to the next section using `moveSectionDown()` after your animation being finished.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // on page load
    $('#uk-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({

        // options
        verticalCentered: false,
        scrollingSpeed: 850,
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

            // after leaving Introduction
            if(index == 1 && direction == 'down') {

                // disable mouse scroll
                $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
                // animation section2
                $('#fr-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);
                // reset section1 flag
                $('#uk-flag').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0);

                // wait 5sec and go section3
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // move section down
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
                    // enable mouse scroll
                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
                    // animation section3
                    $('#de-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);
                    // reset section2 flag
                    $('#fr-flag').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Check this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jidesacibu/3/edit?html,js,output) for a full example.

**EDIT (2014-11-16):**

Using the `afterRender` event you can do what you want right after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({

        // options
        verticalCentered: false,
        scrollingSpeed: 850,
        afterRender: function(anchorLink, index) {
          // disable mouse scroll
          $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
          // animation section1
          $('#uk-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);

          // wait 5sec and go section2
          setTimeout(function() {
            // move section down
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            // enable mouse scroll
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
            // animation section2
            $('#fr-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);
            // reset section1 flag
            $('#uk-flag').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0);
          }, 5000);
        },
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

            // after leaving Introduction
            if(index == 1 && direction == 'down') {

                // disable mouse scroll
                $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
                // animation section2
                $('#fr-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);
                // reset section1 flag
                $('#uk-flag').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0);

                // wait 5sec and go section3
                setTimeout(function() {
                  // move section down
                  $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
                  // enable mouse scroll
                  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
                  // animation section3
                  $('#de-flag').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 5000);
                  // reset section2 flag
                  $('#fr-flag').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Check this other [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/girajubipe/2/edit?html,js,output) to see it in action.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I've been playing around with it, but I can't seem to get it to work for my case—how would I get it to work for the first section only?

Comment: Nice to hear it helps you. Using the `afterRender` event you can do what you want right after page load. I will update my answer in the next minutes to show you how to achieve this.